# How to send Push Notification from device when the receiver device is not in foreground state using FCM in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a one to one chat using FCM. I have stuck at one point, I want to send push notification when the device is not in foreground state. I am new to this can anyone suggest me how can I proceed.
Thankyou

Comment: check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nUSoCZlnDo at about 25 minutes into the talk

Comment: Make sure you are sending data message

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bellow code in MyFirebaseMessagingService class:

```
 if (remoteMessage.getData() != null && remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d("TAGRK", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            message = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY);//MESSAGE_KEY is your key for message in your json.(eg. "message")
            title = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get(Config.TITLE_KEY);//TITLE_KEY is your key for title in your json..(eg. "title")
            //send pushnoification method
        } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("TAGRK", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            message = "" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            title = "" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
             //send pushnoification method
        }
```